# Make acpi beep when the power supply being unplugged even if the alsa is turned into mute

Tags: linux, thinkpad, alsa

My laptop is Thinkpad Edge series, of which laptop will produce a beep when the power supply being unplugged. But I noticed that the beep has been blocked if the alsa is turned to mute.

So, I wonder if I can add an exception of "mute rules".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wide variety of sound cards and ac adapters may make this difficult for a universal answer, but the basics are:

- Create a daemon process that monitors /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/state for "offline" (grep will do fine)
- Use that to trigger setting volume to X (see alsactl --help) and playing a sound/beep (aplay, beep, ...)
- Return sound to system setting (the alsa settings are in /etc/asound.state)

Note: if you don't have /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/state, use something else that would change when the cord is pulled ... like /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state (the charging state would become discharging)

Comment: A good idea, but I have no ac_adapter in `/proc/acpi` directory.

Comment: I updated with an alternative file to monitor in /proc/acpi ... it would help if you gave a listing of /proc/acpi and more detailed info of your applicable hardware in general (hardinfo will work ).

Comment: I'll have a try on it. The acpi of my laptop is poorly supported. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can not. Alsa mutes using hardware mixer so well that not even a mouse whisper passes.

Comment: Any other approach to my problem? Any other low-level solutions that can make sound using the device directly?

Comment: 10 years ago there were speaker pins on all motherboards. now they are silently routed to a builtin soundcard.
You may find connector http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker#Pinouts
or you need to solder one. remember that 4-pin connector is sometimes serial 12V and will burn headphones.

Comment: Well..My computer is a laptop and I mean I need a software-level way to achieve that (maybe some kernel hacking on sound devices).

Comment: well snd-hda-intel file has it. replace master channel mute by mute of all but speaker....

Comment: Could you please give me some specific instructions?